# Python: Iterate over two dictionaries that has lists as its values

Tags: python, dictionary, loops

I have constructed two dictionary that contains histogram values of images. Each dictionary has file name of the image file as the key and the list of three one dimension vectors put together as its values.

**Example:** `{'someFileName.jpg' : ['forecolor=2,3,5,5,6','edge=2,4,5','texture=5,4,3']}`

Here is an actual representation of one of my dictionaries:

**Dictionary1**

```
{'/Users/images/Transcend-8GB-Class-10-SDHC-Flash-Memory-Card.jpg': ['fcolor=2,4,14,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,6,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,9,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,6,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,8,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,17,0,0,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,2,3', 'edge=1,252,1,32,124,194,63,252,67,15,240,1,7,244,66,47,0,192,63', 'texture=1,78,27,37,13,6,6,7,78']}
```

Dictionary2

```
{'/Users/images/kodax-camera-M531.jpg': ['fcolor=2,74,6,20,30,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,1,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,5,0,0,0,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0', 'edge=1,4,1,88,128,22,8,39,25,142,230,226,31,60,64,255,252,12,76', 'texture=1,15,32,31,28,19,16,12,98']}
```

My end goal is to pass two of these dictionaries to a method and actually run cosign value,

example: So each dictionary has list as its value, so for each dictionary key i want to do vector multiplication among dictionary1's key1, velu1 with dictionary2 key1, value1,

I have the vector multiplication function so what I am trying to figure out how to properly iterate, I was thinking along the line of using a yield function but it didn't really work when I tried. This is what I have so far:

```
def cosignSimilarity(image1VectorDict, image2VectorDict):
    for image1Key, image2Value in image1VectorDict.iteritems():
        print image1Key
        for aValue in image1Value:
            print aValue
            for image2Key, image2Value in image2VectorDict.iteritems():
                for eValue in image2Value:
                    print aValue
                    print "\n"
                    print eValue
```

FYI: I am not asking help on the cosign calculation.

This is how my current code is spitting the data out if I can isolate key to key from one dictionary to another then I can do the rest such as calculating cosine values.

```
   First  Dictionary
    {'/Users/test/Transcend-8GB-Class-10-SDHC-Flash-Memory-Card.jpg': ['fcolor=2,4,14,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,6,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,9,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,6,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,8,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,17,0,0,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,2,3', 'edge=1,252,1,32,124,194,63,252,67,15,240,1,7,244,66,47,0,192,63', 'texture=1,78,27,37,13,6,6,7,78']}
    ------------------
Second Dictionary
    {'/Users/test/kodax-camera-M531.jpg': ['fcolor=2,74,6,20,30,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,1,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,5,0,0,0,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0', 'edge=1,4,1,88,128,22,8,39,25,142,230,226,31,60,64,255,252,12,76', 'texture=1,15,32,31,28,19,16,12,98']}
    ++++++++++++++++++
    /Users/test/Transcend-8GB-Class-10-SDHC-Flash-Memory-Card.jpg
    fcolor=2,4,14,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,6,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,9,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,6,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,8,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,17,0,0,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,2,3
    fcolor=2,4,14,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,6,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,9,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,6,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,8,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,17,0,0,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,2,3


    fcolor=2,74,6,20,30,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,1,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,5,0,0,0,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
    fcolor=2,4,14,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,6,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,9,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,6,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,8,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,17,0,0,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,2,3


    edge=1,4,1,88,128,22,8,39,25,142,230,226,31,60,64,255,252,12,76
    fcolor=2,4,14,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,6,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,9,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,6,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,8,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,17,0,0,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,2,3


    texture=1,15,32,31,28,19,16,12,98
    edge=1,252,1,32,124,194,63,252,67,15,240,1,7,244,66,47,0,192,63
    edge=1,252,1,32,124,194,63,252,67,15,240,1,7,244,66,47,0,192,63


    fcolor=2,74,6,20,30,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,1,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,5,0,0,0,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
    edge=1,252,1,32,124,194,63,252,67,15,240,1,7,244,66,47,0,192,63


    edge=1,4,1,88,128,22,8,39,25,142,230,226,31,60,64,255,252,12,76
    edge=1,252,1,32,124,194,63,252,67,15,240,1,7,244,66,47,0,192,63


    texture=1,15,32,31,28,19,16,12,98
    texture=1,78,27,37,13,6,6,7,78
    texture=1,78,27,37,13,6,6,7,78


    fcolor=2,74,6,20,30,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,1,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,5,0,0,0,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
    texture=1,78,27,37,13,6,6,7,78


    edge=1,4,1,88,128,22,8,39,25,142,230,226,31,60,64,255,252,12,76
    texture=1,78,27,37,13,6,6,7,78


    texture=1,15,32,31,28,19,16,12,98
```

Obviously as you can see I am spitting out way to many repetition of same value

These are the actual dictionaries that I am dealing with:

**Dictionary 1:**

```
{'/Users/test/Transcend-8GB-Class-10-SDHC-Flash-Memory-Card.jpg': ['fcolor=2,4,14,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,6,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,9,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,6,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,8,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,17,0,0,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,2,3', 'edge=1,252,1,32,124,194,63,252,67,15,240,1,7,244,66,47,0,192,63', 'texture=1,78,27,37,13,6,6,7,78']}
```

**Dictionary 2:**

```
{'/Users/test/kodax-camera-M531.jpg': ['fcolor=2,74,6,20,30,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,1,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,5,0,0,0,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0', 'edge=1,4,1,88,128,22,8,39,25,142,230,226,31,60,64,255,252,12,76', 'texture=1,15,32,31,28,19,16,12,98']}
```

**I have lamba function**

```
cosinLamba = lambda a, b : round(NP.inner(a, b)/(LA.norm(a)*LA.norm(b)), 3)
```

*I want to iterate over dictionary 1 and dictionary 2 and get the fcolor value of dictionary1* `'fcolor=2,4,14,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,6,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,9,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,6,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,8,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,17,0,0,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,2,3'`

*and fcolor value of dictionary2*

```
'fcolor=2,74,6,20,30,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,1,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,5,0,0,0,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0'
```

Send them to my lamba function `cosinLamba(valu1, value2)` ***value1 and value 2 are strings and thats why I have saved them in my dictionary these as values.*** And I want to do for fcolor, texture, edge all the vectors that I have stored for given picture in each dictionary.

Comment: image2Value should be image1Value in the 1st line

Comment: Should this be cosineSimilarity? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity

Comment: @gnibbler yes it is cosineSimilarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could start by changing your representation to:

```
{'someFileName.jpg' : {'forecolor': [2,3,5,5,6],'edge': [2,4,5],'texture':[5,4,3]}}
```

Or

```
{('someFileName.jpg', 'forecolor'): [2,3,5,5,6],
 ('someFileName.jpg', 'edge'): [2,4,5],
 ('someFileName.jpg', 'texture'):[5,4,3]}
```

For example, to get corresponding lists for the 1st case:

```
from itertools import product

# pair info for each image with info of every image from another dictionary
for (fn1, d1), (fn2,d2) in product(dict1.iteritems(), dict2.iteritems()):
    for property_, list_value in d1.iteritems():
        compute_cosine_similarity(list_value, d2[property_])
```

Using your representation with list of string it looks like:

```
from itertools import product

# pair info for each image with info of every image from another dictionary
for (fn1,lst1), (fn2,lst2) in product(dict1.iteritems(), dict2.iteritems()):
    # assume all lists has the same order of elements
    for string_value1, string_value2 in zip(lst1, lst2):
        compute(string_value1, string_value2)
```

You shouldn't store numbers as a list of ascii strings. If you need to save memory you could use numpy arrays. `cosinLamba` already accepts them.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import numpy as np

Info = namedtuple('Info', 'forecolor edge texture')

dict1 = {'someFileName.jpg': Info(np.array([...], dtype=np.uint8),
                                  np.array([...], dtype=np.uint8),
                                  np.array([...], dtype=np.uint8))}
```

The code to call cosine_similarity() is exactly the same as for your representation.

Comment: so in the first case you are constructing dictionary within dictionary right.. my image histogram digesting code is pretty lengthy so thats why I trying to reduce that i do at memory. So I construct a string and key value and save it to dictionary

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: first make it work for small samples. Later you could test your optimized for memory/speed versions against the correct version with clear specification. If memory is an issue you could use numpy arrays later. Does the code in the answer produce expected result?

Comment: NO it doesn't because I first have to get my dictionary representation similar to your case 1 could you explain how the case 1 data structure looks like. so each vector is in dictionary?

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: Could you construct by hand (in whatever representation you understand) two input dictionaries and the expected result? And add this info to the question.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: I've updated the answer with code that uses yours list of string representation

Comment: Thanks alot for explaining in details and guiding me towards to the correct solution I am going to change my dictionary representation and use the what you suggest. I just try the solution and it perfectly out my results. But I want to use the numpy so I am going to change the course.

Comment: One quick question not sure if I should open a different thread when I try to convert the string to np.array I get this error:     v1fColor = NP.array([v1fColor], dtype=NP.uint8)
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '2,4,14,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,6,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,9,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,6,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,8,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,17,'

Comment: [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide a minimal example that shows the problem. Mention where do the strings come from and why don't you read your image files directly into numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with the cosign computation that you want to perform, but aside from that, if my understanding of your question is correct, then the following code should work:

```
for key1, vals1 in dict1.iteritems():
    vals2 = dict2[key1]
    for val1, val2 in zip(vals1, vals2):
        # you now have the corresponding values for each image file
        compute_cosign(val1, val2)
```

Comment: Let me try this. I hav eneverused the zip function, but going to read the docs on that. Thanks.

Comment: `zip([1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])` gives `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]`

Comment: they don't share the same key they have different keys and different number of elements

Comment: reason I asked that question is because I am little confuse with this line vals2 = dict2[key1]

Comment: This won't work with the representation as shown, which has them as comma separated lists.